# Manage concurency issue by managing incoming form data with a queue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Note: I am already using `onFormSubmit` and this is where the problem has come from.

I have built a script that manages some data in a shared google sheet. for the most part it works as expected however when several forms are submitted at once I run into a problem where references to last row sometimes overlap and cause 2 rows of data to reference a duplicate row from another sheet. I am hoping to find a method that allows for something like a queue for incoming form data.

I have recently learned that [Lock Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) exist however I am not fully sure that it can be used in the way I want to use it. I am not 100% sure how it should be implemented or which of the several lock services I need to be using.

Can anyone point me in the right direction if there is some kind of queue system for google script to grab incoming form data?

For a reference here is a screen shot of how 2 of the rows of data are referring to the same cell in another sheet due to this concurrency problem.

[image]

here is my code:

```
function AM2(e) {
  var form_name = "Form Responses 1";
  var open_name = "OPEN";

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(form_name);
  var open_ws = workbook.getSheetByName(open_name);

  var frng = form_ws.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var frow = frng.filter(String).length;

  var gid= form_ws.getSheetId().toString();
  var gid_and_data = gid + '&range=D' + frow + '", "' + e.values[2]
  var link_var = '=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet_address_redacted_for_post/edit#gid=' + gid_and_data +'")'

  open_ws.appendRow(['NEW',e.values[1],'',link_var,e.values[4]]);
  var rng = open_ws.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var row = rng.filter(String).length;

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['NEW', 'OPEN', 'COMPLETE', 'PENDING'], true).build();

  open_ws.getRange(row, 1).setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

Comment: Try using [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) Trigger and get your data from the event object instead of the last row.

Comment: @Cooper I am using `onFormSubmit` that is where the problem is. onFormSubmit only activates a function after the data has been sent to the spreadsheet. As far as I can find there is not a way to intercept onFormSubmit and hold it in a queue. I have been working on this and it looks like the only way around this problem is to instead run this code in a timed loop to check if changes have been made. Something like 10min loops should work fine here.

Comment: Yes but I suggest that you get the data from the event object and not the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Cooper I do get the data from the event object and that works to move data to the OPEN worksheet however I still need to save a link back to the original data in the form dump sheet. This is why I need to find a way to handle row count issues.

Comment: So are you trying to go edit data in the linked sheet?

Comment: @Cooper So everything on the form gets sent to the linked sheet and at the same time I get the event and move specific fields to the OPEN sheet. This is so we are only showing information at a high level and when someone wants to see all the details they can click the generated hyperlink that then takes them to the complete form data at the exact cell where the data is. The code does that but when 2 many substitutions come in at once those links end up having the same row num and so they dont link to the correct row on the form page. Again to fix this I am likely going to use a timed loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197061/discussion-between-cooper-and-mike-smt).

Comment: Try `var frow = e.range.rowEnd;`

Comment: @Tedinoz That does not produce any value when receiving form data. That might work while working within a worksheet but does not appear to help here.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Did you check that with a logger? (of course, you did). Well, if that didn't work, then your installable trigger isn't working because that is a standard event object. I suggest you click on Edit Current Projects Triggers, select the trigger and view Failed Executions (the three dot icon) and select the latest start time. View the actual error and copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: @Tedinoz the trigger is working fine. My logger shows that and the data manipulation shows that. `e.range.rowEnd;` is not leaving anything in the log when calling `Logger.log(e.range.rowEnd)`. Are you sure that the `event` from incoming form data will have a `range.rowEnd` value? I can see that if you have like an onEdit event but maybe not from onFormSubmit? Is there a list of all event data that can be received from `onFormSubmit`'s event? I have tried to find a detailed list but with no luck so far.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat; same address as with Cooper the other daY.

Comment: Excellent. Good news.

Comment: It looks like that worked but instead of using `rowEnd` I went with `rowStart`. No more duplicate values are seen in my testing :D. Thanks a bunch.